What is the character [esc][cc][esc]?
esc + cc + esc gives a double-struck lower-case c. It is different, however, from the double-struck c given by esc + dsc + esc (the double stroke is curved in the former but vertical in the latter). Mathematica calls this character "\ConstantC". I can't find any information about its meaning or purpose. To add to the mystery, its Documentation Center page has a bullet point reading "Unicode: F7DA", but no such Unicode character exists.

It is used to represent a CONSTANT, particularly as a result of indefinite integration.  You can find this by FullForm[ ] around your symbol, giving \[ConstantC].

It is used to represent arbitrary constants, e.g., DSolve[y'[x] == y[x], y, x]

If comments could be downvoted I would downvote both two comments above.

@azerbajdzan I found Bob Hanlon's comment helpful because it gives a working example that quickly shows a "use case" for this symbol (that is, a case where Mathematica uses it).

@WillG Actually Mathematica is not using it in his example but instead it uses C[1]. The fact that C[1] is displayed as \[ConstantC] is a different matter.

@azerbajdzan Please be aware that your first comment was flagged as unfriendly. It would have been much better if you had said "I disagree with both of the comments above" and then explained your reason as you did in your last comment.

@C.E. I will try to do better comments. It was not meant to be unfriendly, just like downvoting question or answer is not considered unfriendly, but we do not have this option of downvoting for comments.

There is "Mathematical Double-Struck Small C" in Unicode though, encoded as 1D554 since March 2001 (link). So, was the "\ConstantC" defined by Mathematica since its early days? (before the 1D554 was encoded officially in Unicode)

@azerbajdzan I'm a little confused by your comment, "The fact that C[1] is displayed as \[ConstantC] is a different matter." Suppose I had asked about the meaning/use of the symbol [esc][ee][esc], and someone had replied that it is the mathematical constant $e$. Would you have said something like, "No, E is the constant $e$, and the fact that it is displayed by the same symbol as [esc][ee][esc] is a different matter"?

Admittedly I can enter [esc][ee][esc] and Mathematica treats it as E, whereas I cannot enter [esc][cc][esc] and have Mathematica do something meaningful with it (as far as I know). But the same is true of e.g. C[1] (again as far as I know), so I don't see what distinction you're trying to make.

@WillG ESC+e+e+ESC and E are exactly the same thing. It is just a different method to input the same thing - Eulrer constant. But C in C[1] is not the same as ESC+c+c+ESC. C has special meaning in Mathematica code while the latter is just an ordinary character like any other, say, a.

The \[ConstantC] character is used to format output expressions like C[1], such as those from DSolve. These outputs are actually wrapped in a TemplateBox however, so you can't use \[ConstantC] manually for input, unless you copy-paste one such output.
In[1]:= C[1]

Out[1]= C[1] (*formats with \[ConstantC] in the front-end*)

In[2]:= \[ConstantC][1] === C[1]

Out[2]= False


To answer the second part of your question: U+F7DA is a perfectly valid Unicode character. However, it belongs to the so-called private use area, in which characters do not have a standard definition, but can be used by any application for its own purposes.
You can find this mentioned also in ToCharacterCode:

The Wolfram System defines various additional characters in private Unicode space, with character codes between 57344 and 63743.

